# Nexus 7 issues with Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, windows, nexus-7

Installed updates to nexus 7 to run on 4.4.4 and installed the proper drivers from asus's support. java android teacher had a video on this and followed his steps but still eclipse does not see the nexus and there is only an option for virtual device manager, not just device manager. ran on windows 7 and 8 and mac os. Mac can't find the jre but windows could. solutions?

Comment: Class is online so cant get the teacher to really help but is there an option for device manager cause I only see one for virtual device manager. is there somewhere different the drivers should be for this to work or something with eclipse?

Comment: I have actually had this problem since 4.4.2 and still having it on 4.4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the Google USB driver instead of Asus.

- Here's the guide to downloading the driver: http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html
- Here's the guide on installing it: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver

Note that the Google USB driver page says:

> The Google USB Driver is required for Windows only in order to perform adb debugging with any of the **Google Nexus devices**. The one exception is the Galaxy Nexus: the driver for Galaxy Nexus is distributed by Samsung (listed as model SCH-I515).

Comment: that was on of the first things I did, also put usb debugging on.

Comment: @Ant Ah, try replacing the drivers with the ones provided by Google  using Device Manager. They should be located in your Android SDK folder at extras\google\usb_driver, if they're not then open the SDK Manager and install USB Driver.

Comment: It is telling me in the sdk manager that the google usb drivers are installed already

Comment: Okay that means you have them downloaded, but it's not using them for your device. I edited my answer, look at the second link on how to upgrade the drivers to the Google one. Skip the top part of that guide about OEM drivers and go directly to the Windows 7 subheading.

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to the fact that you do not have USB debugging on for your devices. To do that, you need to activate the developer options from your settings menu. Go go settings --> about phone --> click build number 7 times until the developer options are enabled. Then, enter the developer options and enable USB debugging.

If that still doesn't work, you may need to download the driver for your Nexus. This can be found on the android developer website.

Comment: That is what I did. teacher gave the link for anyone with the nexus 7 the support drivers

Comment: Try to open windows device manager and make sure the driver is correctly associated with the device.